# Is it acceptable to convert composite Z-scores to T-scores (or scaled scores) to improve visualization on a bar/column chart?

Tags: data-visualization, z-score, barplot

My DV is a composite Z-score based on norm-referenced Z-scores on individual tests pooled together. I want to display the means, SD and "significance asterisk brackets" in a pretty standard column graph.

However, I have groups with positive and negative mean values, e.g. group 1 = + 0.36 , group 2 = - 0.76, group 3 = +1.52, etc. This makes creating a pretty graph difficult, so I was thinking about converting the pooled Z-scores in T-scores (Z-scores*15 + 50) or Scaled Scores (Z-scores*3 + 10) so I can have positive values only. The graph would be part of a published article. Is this something acceptable and has it been done before?

Comment: Your zero at present has some meaning. Arbitrary additions will throw that meaning away. If you plot what you have as a bar chart, some groups will plot above and some below zero. What's the problem with that which would be improved by what you propose?

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. With regards to T-Scores and Scaled Scores, I believe they are not arbitrary. T-Scores have a 50 mean and  SD of 15, and Scaled Score a mean of 10 and SD of 3. They are similar to the Z-score, and valid measures per se. However, they are less frequently reported, unless the source test provides them directly. The problem with Z-scores is that I have two groups with values very close to 0. For those groups, the "column/bar" heights are very small and pretty much merge with the axis, leaving only an error bar. See example here : http://imgur.com/oyWjIwN

Comment: By the same logic adding 1.23456 or 3.14159 would not be arbitrary either: I call 50, 15, 10, 3 what they seem, arbitrary constants. If one scale appeals as a matter of convenience, so be it. Nothing I know about obliges you to use bar charts here. Plotting means as point estimates, not bars, is a clear alternative.

Comment: More precisely, bars that encode say 15, 15.5, 14.5 are going to be more difficult to compare than bars that encode 0, 0.5, -0.5, and so on. Consider also the numerous deficiencies of bar plus error bar plots, so-called dynamite or detonator plots. http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/TatsukiRcode/Poster3.pdf is token of wider views.

Comment: I agree re: 15,15.5,17,18 being less intuitive to compare than +.15 and -.25. That's a good point. Also, regarding the example image I posted, I wonder if that is something you saw before? (one bar with a height of 0 and only an error bar crossing the X axis). 

This poster is very informative and eye-opening about the loss of information when using averaging measures, thanks for the link.